# Riesz representation theorem $\mathbb{P}_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, riesz-representation-theorem

What I have given is the Riesz representation theorem. I don't really understand how it works.

Let $\mathbb{P}_2$ be the vector space of polynomials with the highest degree of 2.
Find the riesz representants for $1,x$ and $x^2$

$<p_1,p_2>:=\int_{-1}^{1}p_1(x)p_2(x)dx$

Riesz Theorem:
Let $H$ be a Hilbert Space and $F \in H^{*}$.
Then there exists exactly one $u \in H$ sucht that
$<u,v>=F(v)$ for all $v$ in $H$

For example:
Let u=x then <x,v> should equal F(v) for every v in $H$, how do I find the right F?

I didn't study functional analysis until now, but need to understand the results.
I would be thankful if somebody could explain it to me.

Comment: You can find the right $f$ as given in the constructive proof of the Riesz representation theorem on Wikipedia

Comment: @FShrike my idea was to get a Basis in this case ${1,x,x^2}$, and then calculate $<1,1>$ , $<1,x>$ and $<1,x^2>$ because F is linear and a linear function is defined my its values for the elements of the basis this should be F for u=1. (This Theorem is the first time I got in touch with functional analysis, I don't think I would be able to understand the proof at all)

Comment: I don’t know much functional analysis myself. I’m not sure how $x$ is a member of the dual space of $P$: do you mean find the linear functional in $P^*$ such that its Riesz representation is $x$?